# Morphia not applying sparse option to my index

Tags: java, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, morphia

I'm trying to use Morphia to interface with MongoDB, and my Morphia entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(some params about storing the entity)
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    <Some other fields here>
    @Indexed(options =
            @IndexOptions(unique = true, sparse = true)
    )
    private String field; 
    <Some other fields here>
}
```

I would like this field to be unique if present, but not required (and not unique if not present; multiple entries should be able to exclude this field).  My understanding of how to do this is with a unique sparse index, as I've tried to set up.

The problem I'm running into is that when I check the index configuration in Studio3T, it appears that my index is being created as unique, but the sparse property is not applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: Upon further research, this appears like it might be an issue with Microsoft Azure CosmosDB.  When I run this code locally, it works fine, but it does not create the sparse index properly on Azure CosmosDB.  Updating tags accordingly.

Comment: This actually works for me on master which is essentially as 1.3.2...

Comment: @evanchooly I was working on a different part of my project for the last few days and haven't had a chance to test this.  Apparently, when I run this code with a local instance of MongoDB on my machine, it works fine; the problem appears to be when I try to connect it to Microsoft Azure CosmosDB.  Can you test/verify this, or is this outside the scope of Morphia?

Comment: If indexes aren't getting properly created on CosmosDB, then it's well outside Morphia's scope.  It works on MongoDB, fwiw.  I've never used CosmoDB so I don't really have much to say on that subject.

Comment: Yeah, I've confirmed that this seems to be a CosmosDB issue and updated the tag accordingly.  Thanks for your help :)