# MongoDB (or Morphia) conditional reference

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a MongoDB collection C whose schema contains a manual reference to another collection D, and I'm using Morphia in Java to manage both C and D.  D has a boolean field b in its schema, and I would like to validate my reference against b (i.e. when a new document c is written to collection C, if its reference points to some entity d in the D collection, then if the boolean value b of d is false, then MongoDB should throw an error).

To describe a bit more concretely, let's say you have 2 standard POJOs to represent the MongoDB collection schemas:

```
class C {
    @Id
    public String id;

    @Reference
    public D target; 
}

class D {
    @Id
    public String id;

    public boolean b;
}
```

Based on this schema, a sample insert operation would look like this (JSON):

```
{
    "target" : { "id": "MY_FANCY_ID" }
    //There is a record with id = "MY_FANCY_ID" in collection D
}
```

When inserting a new C with a non-null target (D), I would like to check if target.b is false, and if it is, then throw a database error.

1) Is there a way to do this natively in MongoDB?
2) If not 1), then is there a way to manage this in Morphia (without some extremely obtuse and verbose hack)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should just add validation in C.setTarget()

Comment: The problem is that I want C to be a POJO as much as possible, I don't want to inject a Datastore into my POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively to MongoDB, you're out of luck.  With Morphia you could use something like `@PerPersist` to do the extra query to check for that boolean value.  It would mean an extra query every time you save a C unless you engineer some shortcut to only do the query on an initial insert.  Checking if the ID is null might help here.

Comment: Thanks Evan!  Good to hear from the lead dev for Morphia himself :)  Checking if the ID is null is unfortunately not good enough here; null is actually a valid D in this case (the reference is nullable).  But good to know there is no easy workaround that I was missing.

Comment: Also, if you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at this other question which has been outstanding for about a week or so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884690/morphia-not-applying-sparse-option-to-my-index